# How to change the arrow color of ' select' in a form with CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

I currently have a form with a transparent background on a black page background and am unable to see the arrow on the 'select' in a drop down menu.
Can someone please shed some light on how to change the color of the arrow?

```html
<p class="wysija-paragraph wysija-date">
<label>Birthday</label>
<select class="wysija_date_day " name="wysija[field][cf_1][day]" placeholder="Day">
  <option>example option</option>
  <option>example option</option>
  <option>example option</option>
<select class="wysija_date_month " name="wysija[field][cf_1][month]" placeholder="Month">
  <option>example option</option>
  <option>example option</option>
  <option>example option</option>
<select class="wysija_date_year " name="wysija[field][cf_1][year]" placeholder="Year">
  <option>example option</option>
  <option>example option</option>
  <option>example option</option>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with native dropdowns.

You would need to use a custom dropdown component such as ddSlick:

http://designwithpc.com/plugins/ddslick#demo